# windows 7 no password after resume from sleep?

Tags: windows-7

How can I disable the system asking for the password after resuming from sleep in Windows 7?

I would like to be able to use it straight away after resuming from sleep instead of having to enter the password every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For actual sleep (hibbernation) the instructions are [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7771/prevent-windows-asking-for-a-password-on-wake-up-from-sleepstandby/):

- Just head into Power Options in Control Panel, then click the “Require a password on wakeup” on the left-hand side.
- Then click the “Change settings that are currently unavailable” link…
- Click Prevent Windows Asking for a Password on Wake Up from Sleep/Standby

(Follow the above [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7771/prevent-windows-asking-for-a-password-on-wake-up-from-sleepstandby/), it has screenshots which are easier to understand).

.

For shorter periods, you'll probably need to do the same for the screensaver too:

- Go to the "Control Panel".
- Click on "Appearance and Personalization".
- Click on "Change Screen Saver".
- Unclick "On resume, display logon screen".

([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/disable-automatic-lock-with-windows-7/daef8f0a-810f-46e8-9420-3c32c4bd6479))

Comment: I just noticed I don't have admin rights to change the configuration. Grrrrr...